# Effective way to map 15k cities in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, dataframe

I have a data set of around 15k observations. This observations are city names from all over the world. This Data set has been populated by people from many different countries which means that i have several duplicates of the same city in different languages. see below DF extract:

`city_name
bruselas
brussel
brussels
brussels

brussels  auderghem 
bruxelles
bruxelles belgium
munchen
munchenstein
munchwilen
munderkingen
mundolsheim
mungia
munguia
munich
munich

munich

munich  germany
munich  munchen 
munich rupert mayer strasse`

The task is to map all cities in the DF to its english name but, becaue the cities are in different format and in different languages i am finding it very difficult to come up with a solution other than perform this task manually which is not productive as we have 15,000+ observations to go through. The final data set should look something like this(using a few of the observations above only):

`city_name              mapped_city
brussels  auderghem     Brusels
bruxelles               Brusels
bruxelles belgium       Brusels
munchen                 Munich

munich  germany         Munich`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just an idea: Go to wikipedia and crawl the "read in a different language" links? Somewhat unsurprisingly, Google Maps is also pretty good at identifying city names in different languages (including with or w/o country and misspellings).

Comment: I would map to Brussels with double s though.

Comment: Another method could be to get a list of all cities with all their translations mapped to their English one. You could then do a merge or map to the English equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use Google Maps or OpenStreetMap to search for those places and see what they return. Both seem to be capable of handling queries in different languages (e.g. München/Munich, Beijing/Peking), with or without the country, and some misspellings (e.g."munchen" without the "ü").

AFAIK, the Google Maps API is not free-for-use, but the OSM API should be, and in any case, you can just issue a GET request to both and parse the result. For example, for OpenStreetMap:

```
import requests, re, json

lst = {'bruxelles', 'munguia', 'munich rupert mayer strasse', 'munchen', 
       'mundolsheim', 'munchenstein', 'munich', 'brussels', 'munich  germany', 
       'bruselas', 'brussels  auderghem ', 'munderkingen', 'mungia', 
       'munchwilen', 'bruxelles belgium', 'munich  munchen ', 'brussel'}

query = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=%s"
for x in lst:
    response = requests.get(query % x)
    matches = re.findall(r'"placename": (".*?"),', response.text)
    print(x, "-->", json.loads(matches[0]))
```

The result is not perfect, e.g. some results are a bit too specific, but there are other attributes you could use, e.g. the "type" (which should probably be "city"). With some cleanup and some more tinkering this should get you started.

```
munich --> München
munderkingen --> Munderkingen
munich  munchen  --> Johanniter-Unfall-Hilfe e.V., Regionalgeschäftsstelle
mungia --> Mungia
brussels  auderghem  --> Auderghem - Oudergem
munchwilen --> Münchwilen
bruselas --> Bruxelles / Brussel
bruxelles --> Bruxelles / Brussel
munguia --> Mungia
munich rupert mayer strasse --> Rupert-Mayer-Straße
mundolsheim --> Mundolsheim
bruxelles belgium --> Bruxelles / Brussel
munchen --> München
brussels --> Bruxelles / Brussel
munchenstein --> Münchenstein
munich  germany --> München
brussel --> Bruxelles / Brussel
```

The same should work for Google Maps, too, with a similar request, but the results seem not to be as easy to parse as with OSM.

(Disclaimer: Not sure if they are too thrilled if you spam them with 15k such requests, you might want to spread those out a bit, or use a more official API than just HTTP requests. You definitely should cache the results of both, complete search queries (to tweak which attributes to use without querying again) and the mapped cities in case of duplicate user-specified cities in order to minimize the number of requests, and thus both their server load and your running time.)

Comment: Nice, this will defo come in handy thanks for the edit as well

Comment: @tobias_k this solutions seems to work but when i imput my whole list of cities i get this error `IndexError: list index out of range` and i have no idea why as we are not invoking a specific index if that makes sense?

Comment: @RaulGonzales I guess that would then be here: `json.loads(matches[0])` Maybe there's one query that does not yield any results at all. Generaly, you should in practice probably not just take the first result but also look at other attributes like e.g. the type (whether it's a city, or e.g. a restaurant).

Answer (score 3):

Using Fuzzy Wuzzy which uses the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')
print(df.head(5))
0     brussels
1    auderghem
2    bruxelles
3    bruxelles
4      belgium
```

we need a master list of cities to use as a lookup I assume you know what the cities are, i'll use this one from github.

```
cities = pd.read_csv('https://datahub.io/core/world-cities/r/0.csv')

choices = df['City Names'].to_dict()
lookups = cities['name'].tolist()


res = [(lookup,) + item for lookup in lookups for item in process.extract(lookup, choices,limit=2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["lookup", "matched", "score", "idx"])

print(df)
  lookup    matched  score  idx
9401     Munich     munich    100   13
12612    Mungia     mungia    100   10
9400     Munich     munich    100   12
1820   Brussels   brussels    100    0
12613    Mungia    munguia     92   11
...         ...        ...    ...  ...
27205    Желино  auderghem      0    1
27204    Желино   brussels      0    0
27487   Зуунмод  auderghem      0    1
27486   Зуунмод   brussels      0    0
27212    Теарце   brussels      0    0
```

Naturally, if you edit the lookup data frame before hand to keep only the cities you know are in your list then that will make the lookup run faster and return results that you need.

for e,g

```
lookups = ['brussels','munich']

print(df.sort_values('score',ascending=False))
     lookup    matched  score  idx
0  brussels   brussels    100    0
2    munich     munich    100   12
3    munich     munich    100   13
1  brussels  bruxelles     71    2
```

you can then take the lookup with the highest score.

hopefully this points you in the right direction. I'm no expert with this library so it would be best to peruse the documentation for your use case to optimize your code. 
Best of luck.

Comment: @Datanovivce  thanks for that but unfortunately as the number of cities gets bigger the code takes way longer to run and then crashes. I had it running all weekend and crashed yesterday evening.

Comment: @RaulGonzales I thought that might be the case if you used the cities dataset, did you use your own lookup table?

Answer (score -1):

Try mapping by first letters of a city that will reduce your work load

Comment: Hey Seci, I know it's hard when you can't leave comments but answers like this are hardly useful, why not post an example with some code to help others out?